# Can I place a children sprite below it's parent using zPosition

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am adding a sprite to a parent and it shows up on the screen. However despite my zPosition parameter the child is on top of it's parent. I need to get it as defined in the zPosition.

It will be placed correctly if just adding the sprite to self but not as a child to "hjNode".

The current result is that d5Node, the child, is placed above the hjNode (parent).

The zPosition works among the added child's when adding additional child's.

When reading the programming guide i get the feeling, unless i missed something, that this may be a problem.

Would someone know if this is possible?

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {


    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    SKSpriteNode *hjNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Hj"];
    hjNode.position = CGPointMake(150, 300);
    hjNode.zPosition = 100;
    hjNode.name = @"hjNode";
    [self addChild:hjNode];

    SKSpriteNode *d5Node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"D5"];
    //d5Node.position = CGPointMake(170, 320);
    d5Node.position = CGPointMake(-10, -20);
    d5Node.zPosition = 1;
    d5Node.name = @"d5Node";
    [hjNode addChild:d5Node];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be possible, but even if it is not there's a better solution that gives you greater flexibility in the long run.

Instead of adding two child sprites to a sprite node, create a regular SKNode and add all three sprites as children to it. That way you're free to re-arrange them in whatever way you see fit, while all three will follow the position changes of their parent node.

Answer (score 29):

To add to this, if you want to do it the original way described you would give the children a negative zPosition.

According to the [SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html), the zPosition of children are relative to the height of the parent. From the question, d5Node, actually has a zPosition = 101 not 1. Setting the zPosition = -1 will result in a zPosition of 99.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, it is on topic and fast.

Answer (score -1):

Children are always on top of their parents (true in life and in Sprite!).

The zPosition is only relative to children within the same node. Therefore you have to add Hj and D5 to the same node as you are adding the parent to; to enable zPosition of the parent to be relative to the other two nodes.

As LearnCocos2D suggested it might be easier to introduce an extra node (however LearnCocos2D implied the original code would work - it won't).